# dlopen returns NULL after app kill

Tags: ios, dlopen, dynamic-library

I'm using `dlsym` to load private APIs (required on iOS 9.3) :

```
handle = dlopen(CORETELPATH, RTLD_LAZY);
_CTServerConnectionCreate = dlsym(handle, "_CTServerConnectionCreate");
```

When I kill the app (swipe from bottom on multitask mode) and restart app, it crashes on the second line.

The `handle` is equal to `NULL` and I didn't succeed in loading the lib twice.

I tried to get the error with `dlerror()`, but it returns also `NULL`.

Does anybody got this issue ? How to resolve it ?

**Edit :** 
Here is the full code ; with the `if (handle != NULL)` the app doesn't crashes, but private frameworks won't load also

```
#define CORETELPATH "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony"

handle = dlopen(CORETELPATH, RTLD_LAZY);
            NSLog(@"DL Error : %s", dlerror());
            if (handle != NULL) {
                _CTServerConnectionCreate = dlsym(handle, "_CTServerConnectionCreate");
                CTResultConnection = _CTServerConnectionCreate(NULL, simMonitorCallback, NULL);
                _CTServerConnectionAddToRunLoop = dlsym(handle, "_CTServerConnectionAddToRunLoop");
                _CTServerConnectionAddToRunLoop(CTResultConnection, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
                _CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification = dlsym(handle, "_CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification");
                _CTServerConnectionUnregisterForNotification = dlsym(handle, "_CTServerConnectionUnregisterForNotification");
                _CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification(CTResultConnection, kCTSIMSupportSIMStatusChangeNotification);
                _CTServerConnectionGetSIMStatus = dlsym(handle, "_CTServerConnectionGetSIMStatus");
                _CTServerConnectionCopyMobileEquipmentInfo = dlsym(handle, "_CTServerConnectionCopyMobileEquipmentInfo");
            }
```

Comment: Please show your error handling code (i.e. the check for `!handle` and error reporting).  Also what is `CORETELPATH` set to?

Comment: Here it is : `#define CORETELPATH "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony"`. I have edited the previous message - with the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that changing Private API path to public fix the issue ; and the call to private APIs still works :

```
#define CORETELPATH "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony"
```

Comment: `dlerror()` does not report anything even with PrivateFramworks